# Why the number of registers indicated in the invoke-kind/range instruction not matching with the number of argument types?

Tags: android, dalvik, smali

in the following example bytecode:

```
 invoke-virtual/range {v0 .. v5}, Landroid/location/LocationManager;->requestLocationUpdates(Ljava/lang/String;JFLandroid/location/LocationListener;)V
```

The range of registers indicates registers `v0`,`v1`,`v2`,`v3`,`v4`,`v5`, are passed to the method, but why the number is not the same as the number of the types indicated, which is only 2??

Is there difference between invoke-kind/range and normal invoke-kind?

Comment: where did you get that output?

Comment: @auselen The current output is from apktool

Comment: check usage of invoke-virtual/range on http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/dalvik/docs/dalvik-bytecode.html, it has some registers used for specific purposes which in your case looks like sums up to 5. I still can't imagine why you have 6 used but probably remaining is also used for a specific purpose.

Comment: @auselen http://s.android.com/tech/dalvik/dalvik-bytecode.html is the authoritative documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a total of 4 parameters mentioned in the parameter list, `Ljava/lang/String;`, 
`J`, `F`, and `Landroid/location/LocationListener;`. In addition, since is is a non-static method, there is an implied `this` parameter that occurs before the other paremeters. The final missing piece of the puzzle is that 'J' is a double, which is a 64-bit type - meaning it requires two registers.

So the parameters are:

```
this - v0
Ljava/lang/String; - v1
J - v1 and v2
F - v3
Landroid/location/LocationListener; - v4
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you! Really didn't know that `v1` and `v2` will be packed together for J type value!

Answer (score 0):

OK... those types are not separated by `,`, which made it hard to distinguish for beginners:   the `Ljava/lang/String` is the full class name, `J` is for long type, `F` is for float type,`Landroid/location/LocationListener` is for full class name. 
However, still not clear, for all the parameter types specified, plus the `this` type of object that the method is invoking on,  the number is 5 parameter types, but why the range of the registers is specified to be 6?

Comment: From @jesusFreke answer , what i understood is ,Among 6 parameters, four parameters are used for , Ljava/lang/String;, F, and Landroid/location/LocationListener and 1 parameter is used for **this** parameter, the left over 2 parameters are used in J only as its size is 64 bits and 2 registers are needed .